# Visual Studio C++ Project File CustomBuild Task: Filter OutputItemType by File Extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

I have defined a custom build step in a Visual Studio 2019 C++ project file (*.vcxproj*) that generates *.h* and *.cc* files.  There is a Custom Build Tool option entitled *"Add Outputs to Item Type"*, where I can select one of *"C/C++ header"* or *"C/C++ compiler"*.  Is there some way to edit the resulting project file such that the *.cc* files are added as *"C/C++ compiler"* and the *.h* files are added as *"C/C++ header"*?

My intended work-around is to simply remove the generated *.h* files from the list of Custom Build Tool outputs.  That work-around has the disadvantage that the build will fail if one of the *.h* files is missing or stale.  I'm hoping for a solution that resolves this deficiency.

The following illustrates what I have attempted within the *.vcxproj* file:

```
<OutputItemType Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.cc'">ClCompile</OutputItemType>
```

Comment: Where did you put this line in? In a property group, ItemGroup, ItemDefinitionGroup, or in one Item? Could you share some more details about your custom build step script in vcxproj?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how you define the `Custom Build Step`. But custom build step is not the only way.

For C++ projects, msbuild provides Custom Build Tool, Custom Build Step, Build events and [custom targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019). You can achieve same requirements by this script:

```
  <Target Name="CustomTarget" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec Command="xx.exe ..."/> <!--Call the tool.exe to generate files somewhere. We can save them in temp folder.--> 
    <Copy SourceFiles="xxx" DestinationFolder="xxx"/> <!--Use copy task to copy the generated files to project folder-->
    <ItemGroup>
      <ClCompile Include="Path of Temp folder\*.cc" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

And see [this](https://riptutorial.com/msbuild/topic/9236/common-item-types--projectreference), I checked some related documents and confirm `OutputItemType` is something about `ProjectReference`. I'm not sure if this syntax supports other Items.